# sendRedirect in custom action class

Tags: liferay, struts, liferay-6, liferay-hook

I am overriding one of the actions of the calendar portlet . I want to do some functionality then redirect to another JSP after that. I tried using the sendRedirect function as follows:
1.

```
String redirect = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest , "redirect");
actionResponse.sendRedirect(redirect);
```

2.

`actionResponse.sendRedirect ("/calendar/view") ;`

3.

```
ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) actionRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
PortletURL url = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(actionRequest), "8", themeDisplay.getPlid(),
PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);
url.setParameter("struts_action", "/calendar/view");
actionResponse.sendRedirect (url.toString()) ;
```

However, none of the methods cause the jsp to redirect to another one.
I am doing so in the processAction function and I am extending the BaseStrutsPortletAction.

Any suggestions how to solve it?

This is my overridden file :

```
public class TestAction extends BaseStrutsPortletAction {
public void processAction(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction, PortletConfig portletConfig,
      ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception {
    String cmdConstants = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, Constants.CMD);
    if (cmdConstants.equals(Constants.APPROVE)) {
        //some function
        actionResponse.setRenderParameter("test", "test");
        originalStrutsPortletAction.processAction(portletConfig, actionRequest, actionResponse);
    }
  }

  public String render(StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction, PortletConfig portletConfig, RenderRequest renderRequest,
      RenderResponse renderResponse) throws Exception {
    String cmdConstants = ParamUtil.getString(renderRequest, Constants.CMD);
    if (cmdConstants.equals(Constants.APPROVE)) {
      if (renderRequest.getParameter("test").equals("test")) {
        return "/portlet/calendar/view.jsp";
      }
    }
    return originalStrutsPortletAction.render(null, portletConfig, renderRequest, renderResponse);
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to override render method also. Set request attribute in processAction and in render method based on attribute return jspPath that will get rendered.

Comment: I tried the following but it was of no help. Any suggestions ? In process action I wrote the following: actionResponse.setRenderParameter("test", "test"); In render I wrote the following : if (renderRequest.getParameter("test").equals("test")) { return "/portlet/calendar/view.jsp"; }

Comment: Can you post the overridden file over here??

Comment: @Danish I added my file to the post above.